# IEnumerable Where() and ToList() - What do they really do?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I was wondering what exactly the `Where()` and `ToList()` methods are doing.  Specifically I was wondering if the `Where()` will create a new object in memory or return a new object.

Ok, looking at the following code, say I have a skeleton log class.

```
public class Log()
{
    public string Log {get;set;}
    public string CreatedByUserId {get;set;}
    public string ModifiedUserId {get;set;}
}
```

In my business logic, say I only want logs created or modified by a certain user.  This is going to be accomplished with a method: `FilterLogsAccordingToUserId()`.

```
public IEnumerable<Log> FilterLogsAccordingToUserId(IEnumerable<Log> logs, string userId)
{
    int user = int.Parse(userId);
    return logs.Where(x => x.CreatedByUserId.Equals(user) ||
                           x.ModifiedByUserId.Equals(user)).ToList();
}
```

In this situation, is `Where()` modifying the `IEnumerable<Log>` by removing all objects that don't match the condition, or is it grabbing all objects, casting that object to a list in memory, and then return that new object?

If it is the second possibility, am I right to be concerned about performance if a sufficiently large list of logs is passed to the function?

Comment: "will create a new object in memory or return a new object", what's the difference?

Comment: Have you read the documentation for the methods in question? See `Enumerable.Where` and `Enumerable.ToList`.

Comment: https://rx.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Ix.NET/Source/Enumerable.cs

Comment: You should test this with Object.ReferenceEquals on items of both your lists.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I might have misinterpreted the asker's intent by adding "or" there. My bad.

Comment: it might be interesting to remark that .Where depends on the type it's used on. It behaves completely different on an IQueryable.

Comment: I'm just passing in a List<Log> in this case.  I was mostly interested in understanding what exactly Where and ToList were doing so that I can write code more thoughtfully in the future rather than optimizing this particular instance.  The example served as more a way to communicate the idea.

Comment: @Aron no need to link to 3rd party sources, go straight to [the source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#577032c8811e20d3)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I wouldn't call the Rx team 3rd party, but yeah. THAT IS SOOOOO AWESOME!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Let's take the two methods separately.

## Where

This one will return a new object, that when enumerated, will filter the original collection object by the predicate.

It will in no way change the original collection, *but it will be linked to it*.

It is also a deferred execution collection, which means that until you actually enumerated it, and *every time you enumerate it*, it will use the original collection and filter that.

This means that if you change the original collection, the filtered result of it will change accordingly.

Here is a simple [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) program that demonstrates:

```
void Main()
{
    var original = new List<int>(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 });
    var filtered = original.Where(i => i > 2);
    original.Add(5);
    filtered.Dump();
    original.Add(6);
    filtered.Dump();
}
```

Output:

[image: LINQPad output #1]

As you can see, adding more elements to the original collection that satisfies the filtering conditions of the second collection will make those elements appear in the filtered collection as well.

## ToList

This will create a new list object, populate it with the collection, and return that collection.

This is an immediate method, meaning that once you have that list, it is now a completely separate list from the original collection.

Note that the objects *in* that list may still be shared with the original collection, the `ToList` method does not make new copies of all of those, but the *collection* is a new one.

Here is a simple [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) program that demonstrates:

```
void Main()
{
    var original = new List<int>(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 });
    var filtered = original.Where(i => i > 2).ToList();
    original.Add(5);

    original.Dump();
    filtered.Dump();
}
```

Output:

[image: LINQPad output #2]

Here you can see that once we've created that list, it doesn't change if the original collection changes.

You can think of the `Where` method as being linked to the original collection, whereas `ToList` will simply return a new list with the elements and not be linked to the original collection.

Now, let's look at your final question. Should you be worried about performance? Well, this is a rather large topic, but *yes*, you should be worried about performance, but not to such a degree that you do it all the time.

If you give a *large* collection to a `Where` call, *every* time you enumerate the results of the `Where` call, you will enumerate the original large collection and filter it. If the filter only allows for few of those elements to pass by it, it will still enumerate over the original large collection every time you enumerate it.

On the other hand, doing a `ToList` on something large will also create a large list.

Is this going to be a performance problem?

Who can tell, but for all things performance, here's my number 1 answer:

1. First know that you have a problem
2. Secondly measure your code using the appropriate (memory, cpu time, etc.) tool to figure out *where* the performance problem is
3. Fix it
4. Return to number 1

Too often you will see programmers fret over a piece of code, thinking it will incur a performance problem, only to be dwarfed by the slow user looking at the screen wondering what to do next, or by the download time of the data, or by the time it takes to write the data to disk, or what not.

First you know, then you fix.

Comment: Nicely explained. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

`Where()` returns a *new* `IEnumerable`. It is a filtered version (a projection) of the original sequence, and original is left unchanged.  `ToList()` returns a new list using the projection.

It's also important to note that calling `.Where()` does not evaluate the projection, that is done when the enumerable is enumerated.  For example, when used in a `foreach` loop, or, in this case, when calling `ToList()`.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Yeah, I should add that.

Comment: +1. Lazy (or deferred) evaluation for `Where` is good note as OP was concerned about where performance cost would be payed if any.

Answer (score 6):

`Where` filters an `IEnumerable<T>` to keep only those elements that satisfy a predicate, maintaining ordering. This does *not* force enumeration of the `IEnumerable<T>` source, so it is declarative in nature.

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        if (predicate(item))
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

`ToList` converts an `IEnumerable<T>` to a `List<T>`, maintaining ordering. This forces enumeration of the entire `IEnumerable<T>` source.

```
public static List<TSource> ToList<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    var list = new List<TSource>();
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        list.Add(item);
    }
    return list;
}
```

> In this situation, is .WHERE modifying the IEnumerable logs by removing all objects that don't match the condition, or is it grabbing all objects from the logs ienumerable, casting that object to a list in memory, and then return that new object?

Your query of the form `logs.Where(...).ToList()` will stream your log items through the `Where` portion, then only place those that satisfy the predicate into the final `List<Log>`.

Answer (score 0):

`Where` will create an iterator that will enumerate through your collection and only return the items that match your predicate. The key thing here is that is will not do this iteration until you actually try to access it (in, for example, a `foreach`) loop.

`ToList` however will copy references to each item in your enumerable collection to a new list (not you are copying the *reference* not the object itself). If you tack a `ToList` on the end of a `Where` then you will cause the `Where` to have to iterate through the collection.

So in short, if you use `Where` you won't be creating any new objects (other than the iterator itself) and you won't change anything in your original collection. If you use `ToList` then you will copy the *references* to the objects that matched your `Where` clause to a new `List` (the original list is, of course, unchanged - unless you assigned it back to the same variable).

So if you don't actually need to create a new list, then don't use `ToList`. If all you need to do is iterate through your collection, just skip the `ToList` part. However, there is a subtle point here, if you do this:

```
var filtered = logs.Where(x => x.CreatedByUserId.Equals(user) ||
                       x.ModifiedByUserId.Equals(user));
```

and then change your collection, and then do this:

```
foreach (var f in filtered) 
{
   //....
}
```

You will be iterating through your original collection (`logs`) as it is *now* not as it was when you declared `filtered`.