# C# List Take by value instead of by reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, linq

I'm having an issue where if I "Take" from a list of strings, it is taking references to those values, so when I go to remove them from the original list, they are also removed from my "taken list".  Is there a way to TAKE by value from a list instead of by reference?  See code below.

```
// ids is a list of strings, use example: ["123","456","789"]
var chunkIds = ids.Take(10);

// right here, chunkIds = ["123","456","789"]

ids.RemoveRange(0, ids.Count < 10? ids.Count : 10);
// after remove the elements we just took from the original list, chunkIds = []
// I want chunkIds to be ["123","456","789"], and ids should be []
```

I'm not seeing any way to do this in the docs (or I'm blind):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Add a `ToList()`. Take is lazy.

Comment: @Caramiriel OMG \*face in hands\*.  that definitely works.  if you want to add that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IEnumerable Where() and ToList() - What do they really do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23090459/ienumerable-where-and-tolist-what-do-they-really-do) - I'll flag it as a duplicate, not quite the same, since it's with `Where` instead of `Take`, but the result is the same. Took me a while to find a good duplicate though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Take`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=netframework-4.8) method (as many other `Linq` methods) is working using deferred execution, you are modifying the source sequence. To make your snippet working you have to convert the `IEnumerable` to `List` or `Array` (to get a new sequence), like that

```cs
var chunkIds = ids.Take(10).ToList();
...
```

Then you'll be able to remove the values from `chunkIds` without affecting the source `ids` sequence